# Best way to serialize a variable list of arguments into an array of bytes in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, arrays, variadic-functions

I have a C implementation where I serialize a variable list of arguments into a byte array.
Thus I can save a certain number of variables into a file.

The code in C looks like this:

```
static uint8_t byte_array[1024];

/* In this example, we assume that fmt contains only 'c', 'i', or 'f'
   We also assume that an argument is available for each char in fmt.
*/

uint8_t * serialize_args(const char *fmt, ...) {
  char *ptr = fmt;
  uint32_t idx = 0;
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, fmt);

  while(*ptr != NULL) {
    char p = *ptr++;
    char c;
    int i;
    float f;

    switch(p) {
      case 'c':  /* serialize char */
        c = va_arg(args, int32_t);
        byte_array[idx++] = (uint8_t) c;
        break;
      case 'i':  /* serialize int */
        i = va_arg(args, int32_t);
        memcpy(&byte_array[idx], &i, sizeof i);
        idx += sizeof i;
        break;
      case 'f':  /* serialize float */
        f = (float)va_arg(args, double);
        memcpy(&byte_array[idx], &f, sizeof f);
        idx += sizeof f;
        break;
    }
  }    
  va_end(args, fmt);

  byte_array[idx++] = 0;
  return byte_array;
}
```

Now let's say I want to translate this in C++. What container would be best suited ?
A vector ? I would then look like this:

```
vector<uint8_t> serialize_args(const char *fmt, ...) {
  char *ptr = fmt;

  vector<uint8_t> byte_array;

  va_list args;
  va_start(args, fmt);

  while(*ptr != NULL) {
    char p = *ptr++;
    char c;
    int i;
    float f;

    switch(p) {
      case 'c':  // serialize char
        c = (char)va_arg(args, int32_t);
        byte_array.push_back(c);  // do I need a cast ?
        break;
      case 'i':  // serialize int
        i = va_arg(args, int32_t);
        // here how do I memcpy to a vector ?
        break;
      case 'f':  // serialize float
        f = (float)va_arg(args, double);
        // here how do I memcpy to a vector ?
        break;
    }
  }    

  va_end(args, fmt);

  return byte_array;
}
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

It's legal to alias any type with a pointer to a character type, so you could do the following (and example for `int`):

```
for (unsigned char* p = &i; p != &i+sizeof(int); ++p)
    byte_array.push_back(*p);
```

or, perhaps more idiomaticaly:

```
std::copy(&i, &i + sizeof(int), std::back_inserter(byte_array));
```

You can also use `memcpy`, but you need to make room for `sizeof(int)` bytes beforehand using vector's `resize` method.

And in C++11 you'd get rid of varargs completely and use a variadic template function.